# Makefile, iterate over dirs and exclude some

Tags: unix, makefile

In a toplevel (unix, GNU) Makefile I want to iterate over a list of subdirs and execute tasks in there but exclude some of them. In this case exclude all subdirs starting with an underscore (_)

The following is working in iterating but ignores the exclusion regex. It still visits dir "_exclude".

In particular I think it ignores the "start of string" ^ (or it takes it literally). I have tried other regexes and they do work. Any idea how to fix that? Or indeed if you have any idea how to eliminate the shelling out or not using GNU makefile extensions?

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
EXCLUDE_DIRS_REGEX=^_
# later addition:
ALLMAKEFILES = $(shell find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Makefile)
SUBDIRS   = $(filter-out ./,$(dir $(ALLMAKEFILES)))

all:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        if [[ "$$dir" =~ $(EXCLUDE_DIRS_REGEX) ]]; then continue; fi; \
        make -C $$dir all; \
    done
```

Comment: If `SUBDIRS` is a variable, try `$(foreach d,$(SUBDIRS),$(patsubst _%,,$(d)))`

Comment: @tripleee excellent idea, thanks. I focussed too much on the shell part. I have amended my post to show where ```SUBDIRS``` come from.

Comment: ```ALLMAKEFILES = $(shell find .  -maxdepth 2 -not -path '*/_*' -type f -name Makefile)``` does the filtering during ```find``` and works well. thanks @tripleee

Comment: Your regex matches strings which start with an underscore, which of course none of the results from `find` will.  `(^_|/_)` would match and underscore either initially or immediately after a slash.

Comment: oh thanks! Now I understand why the bash regex did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems to solve:

1. compute the list of target directories
2. call make in each of them

For the first one a mixture of make and shell functions or built-ins could be something like:

```
REGEX       := ^_
ALLMAKEDIRS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(wildcard */Makefile)))
SUBDIRS     := $(shell for d in $(ALLMAKEDIRS); \
    do ! [[ "$$d" =~ $(REGEX) ]] && echo "$$d"; done)
```

I kept the `REGEX` just in case you have more complex regular expressions or you would like it to be easily modified. But of course if it is exactly `^_` and you never change it the following is simpler:

```
SUBDIRS := $(filter-out _%,$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(wildcard */Makefile))))
```

For the second one your approach is not very make-ish. A better approach would be to have one rule per subdirectory. The following is an example:

```
.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ all
```

It has several advantages:

- there is no need to loop over subdirectories in a complicated recipe, make will do it for you,
- make can launch several jobs in parallel (see the [`-j` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel)) and this will speed-up your build.

Note: calling `make` in a Makefile is not recommended. Prefer `$(MAKE)`. See [this section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) for the details.

Comment: thanks for this. I am all for more "make-ish" solutions!